# start mp4 from specific time

Tags: html, streaming, mp4

i built some half tv script using php. the concept is admin upload video and set the playtime, 
when user access the site video plays automatically with specific time.

url

http://ezwebdesigns.co.uk/onlinetv/index.php

i use videojs player but cant start with specific time, it always start with begining, i set the methods but not working.

anyone know video player with mp4 support that can play video from specific time

Answer (score 0):

Try sth like that:

```
document.getElementById('videoid').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
this.currentTime = 50;
}, false);
```